# Concurrency of Bisector Midpoints in Triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, analytic-geometry

In the triangle $\triangle ABC$, let $BB_1$ and $CC_1$ be the bisectors of angles $B$ and $C$, $B_1$ lies on $AC$, and $C_1$ lies on $AB$. Let $B_2$ and $C_2$ be the midpoints of ${BB_1}$ and ${CC_1}$ respectively. Show that the lines $C_1B_2$, $B_1C_2$, and $BC$ are concurrent if and only if $\angle A = 60^\circ$.

I have tried writing the equation of ${B_2C_1}$ and ${B_1C_2}$ and ${CB}$ in the complex plane and then let P be the intersection of all 3 but the calculations seem too complicated knowing that the equation of a angle bisector has a real parameter.

Comment: Could you do the (hopefully easy) direction when $ \angle A = 60^\circ$? That will show us what techniques you're aware of.

Comment: @CalvinLin I’m not sure how to approach the problem that way.

Comment: Given that you're willing to use complex numbers, and that you tagged it with contest math, I would encourage you to 1/ find lengths using angle bisector theorem/ceva/menelaus theorem, 2/ calculate $ \cos \angle A = \frac{ b^2 + c^2 - a^2 } { 2bc}$ and hope that things cancel out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving this question using vector method.
Let A be the Origin $\vec AB= \vec b , \vec AC = \vec c,  |\vec BC|=a$; using angle bisector theorem, $$\vec B_1= \frac{b}{a+b} \vec c \qquad \vec C_1= \frac{c}{a+c} \vec b$$
$$\vec B_2= {1\over2}\left(\vec b + \frac{b}{a+b} \vec c \right) \qquad \vec C_2= {1\over2}\left(\vec c + \frac{c}{a+c} \vec b \right) $$
lines $C_1B_2, C_2B_1$ meet at some point $Q$ then it is possible to find real parameters  $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that, $$\vec Q= \vec B_1 + \lambda\left( \vec C_2-\vec B_1\right)=\vec C_1+\mu \left(\vec B_2-\vec C_1\right)$$ putting values $\vec B_1, \vec C_1, \vec C_2, \vec B_2$ in terms of $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ (that we have written earlier) and comparing co-eff. of $\vec b, \vec c$ (according to concept of independency of two non colinear vectors) you will get
$$(a-b)\lambda-b\mu+2b=0$$
$$(a-c)\mu-c\lambda+2c=0$$ solving these two. $$\lambda= {2b \over b+c-a}$$

Now, $$\vec Q= \vec B_1 + \lambda\left( \vec C_2-\vec B_1\right)$$
$$= \frac{b}{a+b} \vec c + \lambda \left[{1\over2}\left(\vec c + \frac{c}{a+c} \vec b \right)-\frac{b}{a+b} \vec c\right]$$ as Q is one the line BC,  so sum of co-eff. of $\vec c$ and $\vec b$ $= 1$ from this you will get another value of $\lambda$ in terms of $b,c$

$$\lambda= {2(a+c) \over a-b+2c}$$

equating these two values of $\lambda$ you will finally reach here,
$$b^2 + c^2 - a^2 = bc$$